# Installation metro style application

Tags: installation, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to install my Metro Application.
So, my question is:
Can I move sample pictures for my Application to KnownFolders.Pictures and Videos during installation ?
And, how can I create installation file for my application?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the installation mechanism for Windows Store apps in Windows 8, there is no need to write a setup or installation program. That will all be managed through the Windows Store once your app is published.

Since you can't write a setup program, to accomplish a similar goal, you can put some functionality in the app to execute when it's first run, then save a setting to indicate you've already performed the first run operations.

This would be where you would put your code for moving sample pictures.

However, your app will also need the appropriate permissions to access the KnownFolders location programmatically - check out this article for details. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh967755.aspx

It's also a good best practice to ask the user if it's OK to copy sample pictures to their Pictures library.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I indicate the first run of my Application ? Also, I don't want publish my App on Windows store yet, I want install my app on another machine not via Windows store. And, can you show me some example ? thanks again

Comment: You right click your project and select Store/Create App Packages... Then say you don't want to publish to Windows Store. After that - you end up with a folder and a .appxupload file. Ignore the file and copy the folder to another machine. Then right click the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 file in the folder and select Run with PowerShell. Accept all questions with a "Y" key and it should be done.

Comment: If the setting you choose is not set in application settings - the app is being run for the first time and you should set it, so it never does your first run time setup routines anymore.